# OpenJPA and MySQL auto_increment

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, openjpa

Would you please take a look at my code, I keep getting the following exception when I try to insert a record into the database:

```
Apr 02, 2014 1:30:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [UserEditorServlet] in context with path [/My.Web] threw exception
<openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: error during validation of <unknown>
```

My table is defined like this:

```
create table User (

    id bigint primary key not null auto_increment,
    name varchar(200),
    status varchar(30),
    createdOn datetime,
    modifiedOn datetime,
    password varchar(60),

    index(status)

) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and my identity field like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
protected Long id = null;
```

it turns out that if I assign a value to my id my exception changes to this:

```
Apr 02, 2014 1:37:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [UserEditorServlet] in context with path [/My.Web] threw exception
<openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: Primary key field net.jaimes.Persistent.id of org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ReflectingPersistenceCapable@194765c4 has non-default value. The instance life cycle is in PNewState state and hence an existing non-default value for the identity field is not permitted. You either need to remove the @GeneratedValue annotation or modify the code to remove the initializer processing.
```

While debugging, I only have one null variable: Id, which is expected to be created by MySQL.
At the end, I cannot insert a simple record...

Thank you

Comment: Please post the contents of your persistence.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ReflectingPersistenceCapable

It appears that you are using `openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses` and there are numerous known problems with that feature. If others encounter this problem, please please please refer to the [OpenJPA Entity enhancement](http://openjpa.apache.org/entity-enhancement.html) page on how to **properly** enhance.

Comment: Hi @Rick, yes I'm using that property, I mean, I was. Netbeans has a good integration with the EclipseLink implementation and it's been working great. Thanks for the link, I will definitely take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an OpenJPA bug. After several hours of frustration I tested the same code with EclipseLink and it worked flawlessly.

I also learned that EclipseLink is the reference implementation for JPA. I'm going to stick to it on this project.